How do fix GWT.xml referenced file errors
I cant run my Google Web Application in eclipse. I have a Payara 5 server running my java application. Im running GWT version 2.11, im also running Java 1.8, i am not using Maven. I have also tried earlier versions. It seems to stop working when I enable 'Dynamic Web Module'. I have tried different versions, and tried disabling it, but it doesn't rectify the issue.
I get the below errors:
The errors below were detected when validating the file "gwt-module.dtd" via the file "Test10.gwt.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "gwt-module.dtd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when gwt-module.dtd is validated in the context of Test10.gwt.xml.
AND i also get the below error:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error while downloading 'http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.8.2/gwt-module.dtd' to 'C:\Users\myprofile.lemminx\cache\http\gwtproject.org\doctype\2.11.0\gwt-module.dtd' : '[java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException] C:\Users\myprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\lemminx-temp5715202608397698170\gwt-module.dtd4647482313893390411.lemminx with code: 200 OK'.    Test10.gwt.xml  /test10/src/com/pop line 7  Language Servers
I have tried adding www at the front as some sites suggest. I have tried different GWT versions. I have tried different Java versions. Nothing seems to work

Update your DTD link to be https and www.
https://www.gwtproject.org/doctype/2.8.2/gwt-module.dtd
There is a redirect in place that your browser will use, but it seems that eclipse will not follow it.
